# GORM many to many bulk insert

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

How can we do bulk insert on many to many relationship in GORM?

Let say we have following scenario

```java
class Article{
  static hasMany = [readers:User]
  ...
}

class User{
  static hasMany = [articles:Article]
  ...
}
```

Those mappings will actually create three tables, Article, User_Article (contains many to many data mapping) and User. According to GORM document, adding reader to an article should be done by

```java
article.addToReaders(user)
```

The problem is, when we are going to insert all of existing users as a reader of an article we should iterate through all of the user then add it to the articles reader. which then generate huge amount of SQL statement (inspected through show SQL mode).

How can we optimize it from

```
def users = User.list();
users.each{
   article.addToReaders(it)
}
```

into something that has similar performance (or might be the same one) with following sql code

```
insert into user_article(article_id,user_id) select :article_id as article_id, id from user
```

Hibernate documentation shows that we could use `insert into ... select` statement. But as many to many relationship is not mapped to a domain class, then those HQL could not be used. Any idea all?

Comment: This blog post includes some very useful tips on improving the performance of bulk inserts via GORM http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql

Comment: @Don The article is about data import performance. I'm not sure how it  could be implemented on my scenario. The real bottleneck is on how Hibernate (in this case GORM) works on this scenario. Unless Hibernate could do `insert into ... select` for many to many relationship. I'm still looking for HQL solution before moving into Native SQL. Hopefully it could be done using HQL

Comment: Don't use `hasMany` in both sides, but create a join domain class. See the problems [here](http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/files/169/gorm%20grails%20meetup%20presentation.pdf)